# Loading MEF plugins without restarting web application

Tags: c#, mef

I am developing a web application in .NET that uses in the backend (web api) plugins that are loaded via MEF. In Web API I use Autofac DI and MEF to load plugins.
The problem I encountered is how to replace plugins in production without having to restart the web application (Azure) or IIS pool.
I even planned to host each plugin as one web service so that the application does not depend on plugins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Recomposition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2010/february/managed-extensibility-framework-building-composable-apps-in-net-4-with-the-managed-extensibility-framework#recomposition) is the answer.

In short:

- Mark your plugin import with allow-recomposition
- MEF will trigger re-import every time new plugin appears, or existing dissapear

More samples you'll find here:

https://qube7.com/guides/recomposition.html